# Changing output device for tts program written in C# not working in Windows 10

Tags: c#, windows, audio

When I try to change the output device to my virtual cable in advanced audio settings for my tts console application written in C# the audio plays on my normal device. How do I fix this? Code:

```cs
using System;
using System.Speech.Synthesis;
namespace hhhh
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            Console.WriteLine("Initialized");

            while (true)
            {
                SpeechSynthesizer synthesizer = new SpeechSynthesizer();

                synthesizer.Speak(Console.ReadLine());

            }
        }

       }
    }
```

Comment: I already know how to use it. I don't know why changing the audio device to my virtual cable isn't working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may have to configure `synthesizer` object to listen to in particular device, i.e. default `synthesizer.SetOutputToDefaultAudioDevice()` or for specific targeted device `synthesizer.SetOutputToAudioStream(deviceout, audioformat);`

Have a look at [this documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.speech.synthesis.speechsynthesizer.setoutputtoaudiostream?view=netframework-4.8#System_Speech_Synthesis_SpeechSynthesizer_SetOutputToAudioStream_System_IO_Stream_System_Speech_AudioFormat_SpeechAudioFormatInfo_)

Comment: a example would help. whats deviceout?

Comment: I also think you misunderstood my question. I want to send the audio to a different my virtual cable.